# Stats question concerning standard deviation

Tags: statistics

The volume to which a soda bottle is filled is Normally distributed. 80% of soda bottles are within 0.02 ml of the mean volume of all bottles. Determine the standard deviation of the volumes.

This problem seems to be leaving out crucial information. How can you solve this without knowing the mean?

Answer (score 2):

$Z$ is the standardized normally distributed random variable:$Z\sim \mathcal N(0.1)$. Then you are looking for

$P(-z\leq Z \leq z)=2\Phi(z)-1$

$\Phi(z)$ is the function of the standard normal distribution. This is the area of the pdf from $-z$ to $z$

And $z=\frac{x-\mu_x}{\sigma_x}=\frac{0.02}{\sigma_x}$

$x-\mu$ is $0.02$, because the deviations are at most $0.02$

$2\Phi(z)-1=0.8$

$2\Phi(z)=1.8$

$\Phi(z)=0.9$

If you look at a table of a standard normal distribution you´ll see that

$z=\Phi^{-1}(0.9)=1.28$

Thus the equation is $\frac{0.02}{\sigma_x}=1.28$

Comment: @robjohn Yes, you´re right. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If $X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ is the random fill volume of a single bottle, then the given condition is expressed mathematically as $$\Pr[\mu - 0.02 \le X \le \mu + 0.02] = 0.80,$$ where $\mu$ is the mean fill volume in milliliters.  It follows that $$\Pr[-0.02 \le X - \mu \le 0.02] = 0.80,$$ and dividing by the (as-yet unknown) standard deviation $\sigma$, we get  $$\Pr\left[\frac{-0.02}{\sigma} \le \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \le \frac{0.02}{\sigma} \right] = 0.80.$$  But we also know that $$Z = \frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1),$$ hence our above equation can be written as $$\Phi(0.02/\sigma) - \Phi(-0.02/\sigma) = 0.80,$$ where $\Phi(z) = \Pr[Z \le z]$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution.  But since $\Phi(-z) = 1 - \Phi(z)$ due to the symmetry of the standard normal distribution, we now have $$2 \Phi(0.02/\sigma) - 1 = 0.80,$$ or $$\frac{0.02}{\sigma} = \Phi^{-1}(0.9).$$  $\Phi^{-1}(q)$ is the inverse CDF (or the quantile function):  It represents the value $z^*$ such that $\Pr[Z \le z^*] = q$, so $\Phi^{-1}(0.9)$ in particular represents the $90^{\rm th}$ percentile of the standard normal.  We can either look this up in a table or use a calculator, giving $$\sigma = \frac{1}{50 \Phi^{-1}(0.9)} \approx \frac{1}{50(1.28155)} \approx 0.0156$$ milliliters.

This makes sense if you are familiar with the [68-95-99.7 rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/68%E2%80%9395%E2%80%9399.7_rule), which states that approximately $68\%$ of observations of a normal random variable will lie within $1$ standard deviation of the mean; $95\%$ will lie within $2$ standard deviations of the mean; and $99.7\%$ will lie within $3$ standard deviations of the mean.  Since $80\%$ of observations lie within $0.02$ milliliters of the mean, this suggests to a very crude approximation that $0.02 \approx 1.5 \sigma$; i.e., $80\%$ is very roughly $1.5$ standard deviations if we "eyeball" this rule.  (What $\Phi^{-1}(0.9) \approx 1.28155$ tells us, in fact, is that $80\%$ of observations of a normal random variable will be within $1.28$ standard deviations of the mean.)